# Get breadcrumb in Controller Action

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, ajax, breadcrumbs, dynamic

I need to get the breadcrumb in the controller action because I am using the cache modules(FPC and another system externally). It cached the breadcrumb in the frontend page. With that, I would use `ajax` to get breadcrumb dynamically for better user experience.

The ajax is ready, there's only the breadcrumb part in my controller. Here are the codes made so far:

`Ajax` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j.ajax({
            url: '/fol_carousel/ajax/breadcrumb',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(retorno){
                alert(retorno);
                console.log(retorno);
            }, error: function(x,y,z){
                console.log(x,y,z);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`Controller` code:

```
public function breadcrumbAction(){
    echo json_encode("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `$_crumbs` property is protected in [Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Breadcrumbs.php) I think you'll have to extend the Block and make Magento use it instead of the default variant. In your extended block you could create a method that returns the breadcrumb data as array. Then you retrieve the breadcrumb block by doing `$breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");` and call your method on the variable.

To get Magento to use your block variant you'll need to place something like the following in the `config.xml` of a custom module:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_breadcrumbs>YourModule_Block_Breadcrumbs</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </tag>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```